# The symmetry and two-spin state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, many-body

Suppose that we have a linear two-orbital system which is symmetric around its center (one orbital in left and one in right of the symmetry point) and includes two electrons. It seems that we cannot have triplet spin states, with one electron on each orbital, because of the left-right symmetry of the special two-electron wave function!

I would like to know whether my analyse is correct or not. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is a hoping between the identical spins in the two orbitals and in each orbital there is a Coulumb interaction between the two spins. However, this question is generic and I would like to know the possibility of having triplet in such a symmetric system.

Comment: "symmetric around its center" should spherical symmetry, in which case your orbitals will have certain symmetries...they'll transform as a representation of SO(3). Your left orbital and right orbital fail that criteria.

Answer (score 2):

For *any* system with two available spatial orbitals $|1⟩$ and $|2⟩$ which are orthogonal (or, at least, linearly independent), both spin singlet and spin triplet states are available. To put two electrons in those states, you form the combinations
\begin{align}
|\Psi_\mathrm{triplet,1}⟩ & = \left(|1⟩|2⟩-|2⟩|1⟩\right)|{↑}⟩|{↑}⟩ \\
|\Psi_\mathrm{triplet,0}⟩ & = \left(|1⟩|2⟩-|2⟩|1⟩\right)\left(|{↑}⟩|{↓}⟩ + |{↑}⟩|{↓}⟩ \right) \\
|\Psi_\mathrm{triplet,-1}⟩ & = \left(|1⟩|2⟩-|2⟩|1⟩\right)|{↓}⟩|{↓}⟩ \\
|\Psi_\mathrm{singlet}⟩ & = \left(|1⟩|2⟩+|2⟩|1⟩\right)\left(|{↑}⟩|{↓}⟩ - |{↑}⟩|{↓}⟩ \right) \\
\end{align}
and you're done. All of those combinations are antisymmetric under electron exchange, and that's all that matters.

---

Edit:

I'm unsure where your claim from the comments,

> When we have left-right symmetry (in case with one electron on the left orbital and the other on the right orbital), we expect the spatial part becomes zero.

comes from, but it's just wrong. Here is an example in practice, with two orbitals available (gaussians centered on either side of the origin), in superpositions with even and odd exchange symmetry:

[image]

<sub>Mathematica source: `Import["http://halirutan.github.io/Mathematica-SE-Tools/decode.m"]["https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyRri.png"]`</sub>

The joint wavefunction $\psi(x_1,x_2)$ does indeed vanish on the $x_1=x_2$ diagonal for the odd-symmetry wavefunction (which is the spatial part of the triplet states above), but the two electrons' coordinates are independent, and the wavefunction is very much not zero.

Comment: Thank you for writing exact form of the wave functions. I think the spatial part of the wave functions in the triplet states are zero due to symmetry. Isn't it?

Comment: No, it doesn't vanish. What makes you think it does?

Comment: When we have left-right symmetry (in case with one electron on the left orbital and the other on the right orbital), we expect the spatial part becomes zero.

Comment: @H.Khani I really don't know where the claim comes from or why you think it's true. I've edited with some more detail. But if you just keep repeating the claim (or basically equivalent formulations with no added detail) it will be very hard to understand what key link you're missing and therefore very hard to explain the issue.

Comment: Dear Emilio, I appologise for not providing further details. Please suppose we have a two-orbital system symmetric around the mirror line. I think if one electron is in position $x_1$ (with respect to the mirror line)  the other one must be in position $x_2=-x_1$ because of symmetry. Also, since the two orbitals are identical ($\psi_{\alpha}=\psi_{\beta}$), I expect $\psi_{\alpha}(x_1) \psi_{\beta}(x_2)-\psi_{\alpha}(x_2) \psi_{\beta}(x_1)=0$. Then, we could have only symmetric spatial wavefunction with singlet spin-part of the wavefunction. I will appreciate if you could provide any help.